# Error when returning a generic type

Tags: scala, generics

I have an abstract class that takes generic type and return that type:

```
abstract class Foo {
  def apply[T]:T
}

class FooImpl extends Foo { 
  def apply[Int]: Int = 1 
}
```

However it errors:

```
 error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: Int
       class FooImpl { def apply[Int]: Int = 1 }
```

Why does it happen? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

You're declaring a type parameter named `Int`, which you then use as the return type. So it's different from `scala.Int`.

I think the solution in this case would be moving the type parameter `T` to the class instead of the method:

```
abstract class Foo[T] {
  def apply: T
}

class FooImpl extends Foo[Int] { 
  def apply: Int = 1 
}
```

Comment: Alternately, you can just not redefine the type parameter. Keep `Foo` as is, and for `FooImpl` do ```class FooImpl extends Foo { 
  def apply: Int = 1 
}```

Comment: @Ethan then you are not properly overriding `apply`. Subclasses need it to work for any `T`. The compiler gives the error `class FooImpl needs to be abstract, since method apply in class Foo of type [T]=> T is not defined`

Comment: And I don't want the generic parameter to be at class level. I want it at method level and auto deductable when overriding with a specific type

Answer (score 1):

Bubletan already explained why it doesn't work with `Int` used as type parameter name.

If you don't want to add any type parameters to `Foo`, you can do several things.

1. Use type member:

   ```
   abstract class Foo {
     type T
     def apply: T
   }

   class FooImpl extends Foo { 
     type T = Int
     def apply: T = 1 
   }
   ```

   this allows you to use the common type `T` in multiple methods.
2. You can just use `Any` in the interface, and then specify the more precise type in the implementation:

   ```
   abstract class Foo {
     def apply: Any
   }

   class FooImpl extends Foo { 
     def apply: Int = 1 
   }

   val x: Int = (new FooImpl).apply
   ```

   Here, the compiler will be able to correctly infer the more specific type `Int` when it sees the method `apply` called on `FooImpl`.
3. Could it be that you want to keep `T` as parameter? Then you would have to add at least some kind of implicit argument to method `apply` that allows you to produce a `T`:

   ```
   trait CanCreate[T] {
     def create: T
   }

   trait Foo {
     def apply[T](implicit c: CanCreate[T]): T = c.create
   }
   ```

   Without additional arguments that enable you to generate actual instances of `T`, all you can do is throw an exception (thereby "returning `Nothing`").